# October CMS : How to extend User class to add relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

Hello there i'm new to October CMS and i just started with User class What i know i create relationship in laravel is so easy.

I have extended user plunging.

```
    User::hasCountry()->get();

    public hasCountry($query){
        return $query->where('country',1);
    }
```

SO i have created this relation but i dont know how to add into Extended User class.

I have found one solution

```
public function boot()
{
    User::extend(function($model) {
        $model->addDynamicMethod('hasCountry', function($query) {
            return $query->where('country', 1);
        });
    });
}
```

But it is not extending or adding methode.

Please Help :)

Comment: is country in same table or Country has its own model ?

Comment: country is another model named "Country"

Answer (score 0):

I read the suggested approach.  If I understand it correctly, this idea would alter the Code Base for the OctoberCMS install, which is not ok and could cause havoc when new October Updates are pushed to your app.

Why not just create a new Model using the ***backend_user*** table and then add all the relationships you want?

Example:

```
use Model;

/**
 * Model
 */
class EnhancedUser extends Model
{
   /**
   * @var string The database table used by the model.
   */
  public $table = 'backend_users';       

  public $hasOne = [
        'Country' => 'Acme\Blog\Models\Country' //path of your country model
    ];
 }
```

I believe the right way to add functionality to your App with OctoberCMS is to ***create a custom plugin***, and IMO that would seem to offer the most flexability.

If you need to get your current User to base an instance of your EnhancedUser Model use this:

```
BackendAuth::getUser(); //Returns the authenticated user
```

**BTW:** I found these resources great when learning to build custom plugins for OctoberCMS:

1. (My personal fav and The Lazy Man's Way).  Install the "Builder" plugin and then go here and watch the [How To] Video:

   ***Plugin:***
   http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder

   ***Video:***
   https://vimeo.com/154415433
2. The ***Docs***
   http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration